# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'device_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

Need some help here:

I've tried and googled a lot and can't find the issue. I'm getting this error when tagging a url on a template:

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'device_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

My URLPattern:

```
    url(r'^device/list/$', device_list, name='device_list'),
```

My template call:

```
    <li class="device"><a href="{% url 'device_list' %}">List Device</a></li>
```

My reverse definition on the CVB on models:

```
@require_role('admin')
def device_list(request):
    """
    DEVICE list view
    """
    header_title, path1, path2 = u'List', u'Mgmt', u'LIst'
    posts = DEVICE.objects.all()
    keyword = request.GET.get('keyword', '')
    if keyword:
        posts = DEVICE.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=keyword) | Q(comment__contains=keyword)| Q(ip__contains=keyword)| Q(new_ip__contains=keyword)| Q(mgmtname__contains=keyword)| Q(port__contains=keyword))
    else:
        posts = DEVICE.objects.exclude(name='ALL').order_by('id')
    contact_list, p, contacts, page_range, current_page, show_first, show_end = pages(posts, request)
    return my_render('jasset/device_list.html', locals(), request)
```

Answer (score 0):

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from jasset.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^asset/add/$', asset_add, name='asset_add'),
    url(r"^asset/add_batch/$", asset_add_batch, name='asset_add_batch'),
    url(r'^asset/list/$', asset_list, name='asset_list'),
    url(r'^asset/del/$', asset_del, name='asset_del'),
    url(r"^asset/detail/$", asset_detail, name='asset_detail'),
    url(r'^asset/edit/$', asset_edit, name='asset_edit'),
    url(r'^asset/edit_batch/$', asset_edit_batch, name='asset_edit_batch'),
    url(r'^asset/update/$', asset_update, name='asset_update'),
    url(r'^asset/update_batch/$', asset_update_batch, name='asset_update_batch'),
    url(r'^asset/upload/$', asset_upload, name='asset_upload'),
    url(r'^group/del/$', group_del, name='asset_group_del'),
    url(r'^group/add/$', group_add, name='asset_group_add'),
    url(r'^group/list/$', group_list, name='asset_group_list'),
    url(r'^group/edit/$', group_edit, name='asset_group_edit'),
    url(r'^idc/add/$', idc_add, name='idc_add'),
    url(r'^idc/list/$', idc_list, name='idc_list'),
    url(r'^idc/edit/$', idc_edit, name='idc_edit'),
    url(r'^idc/del/$', idc_del, name='idc_del'),
    url(r'^device/add/$', device_add, name='device_add'),
    url(r'^device/list/$', device_list, name='device_list'),
    url(r'^device/edit/$', device_edit, name='device_edit'),
    url(r'^device/del/$', device_del, name='device_del'),
    url(r'^asset/url/$', web_url_list, name='web_url_list')
```